# Java - Find coordinate of a position in two dimension

Tags: java

I am going to find (x,y) coordinate of a position.
For example, I have a 2D matrix with number of row and col is 11 and 12 as image below:
https://ibb.co/ktmS2H 
How can I find (x, y) coordinate of a position in which has converted to 1D matrix from 2D matrix?
**Input**: a position in 1D matrix, size of matrix 2D (ROWxCOL)
**Output**: (x, y) coordinate of that position in 2D matrix

***Note***: In case matrix 10x10. I can solve it with this solution: 
x = pos / 10
y = pos % 10

Comment: Are you converting your 2D matrix to 1D matrix and want to get the coordinate of a specific element in your 1D matrix?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @yassadi: yes, I mean that

Comment: @TrippKinetics: I just have code for one case with matrix 10x10. But it's not correct for another case. So I need to ask someone here for a solution.

Comment: Share that code. Better than nothing.

Comment: @TrippKinetics I added my code for a case

Comment: I don't understand the reason to rate my question down. Anyone comes here to find the solution, not just code

Comment: As you say, `x = pos / 10; y = pos % 10` is correct when the matrix has dimensions of 10x10. `x = pos / row; y = pos % row`. 
What I make from your question is you want code written for you; SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume they give you the following inputs:

```
n: number of columns.
m: number of rows.
p: position in the 1D matrix.
```

This is what you should do to get x and y:

```
x = p/n
y = (p - x*n) % m
```

The reason for this answer is:

```
x * n + y * m = p
```

Comment: I knew that before, but how can I solve the math : 13 = x * 11 + y ? (relate with my example in image)

Comment: My assumption was you have the 2D matrix, and you need to know where the element is in this 1D matrix, so what are x and y here?

Comment: I have modified my question. Please check again sir

Comment: Do you know the size of the matrix? For example, do you know if the matrix is going to be 3x3?

Comment: of course, I know size of matrix before. I will add it to input condition of my question.

Comment: Please provide an example as well. I think what you mean is in case of a 3x3 matrix, you get (0,5) as input, and should give (1,2) as output. Correct?

Comment: Please look at this image. I wrote detail in there: https://ibb.co/mmvbwc

Comment: Thank you, but it seem has problem with my matrix 11x12. In case p = 20, x = p/n = 2 => wrong the row of 20. The output of 20 must be (1, 9) .

Comment: I think this should reverse to be like this:
n: number of cols.
m: number of rows.
I think your solution is good. I have tested for all cases. But I think the math is enough: y = (p - x*n). Does it need to %m ?

Comment: @Brascelok in fact, it doesn't. I just added it so the person asking the question would understand it better.